No src and sizes attributes present on Wordpress thumbnail images; the smallest image size is loaded irregardless of viewport size
I have set up custom thumbnail sizes in my functions.php, as follows:
function df_theme_support() {
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

  //Custom image sizes
  add_image_size('small-thumbnail', 430, 242, true);
  add_image_size('medium-thumbnail', 645, 363, true);
  add_image_size('medium-large-thumbnail', 860, 484, true);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'df_theme_support');

The problem is that the site is displaying the smallest version (430x242) for all viewport widths. Furthermore there are no src and sizes attribute for the image(s).

All the images are produced correctly and put in the default images folder: /wp-content/uploads/12/

Is there some additional function/method I need to implement codewise to activate responsive images in WordPress (in other words that the src and sizes attributes is applied so that the image changes depending on viewport conditions)?
I thought of using JS and media queries to achive this, but from what I understand there should be "built in" functionality for this in Wordpress already.
I have the gd module installed however not the imagick. Maybe I need imagick installed to get this to work?

can you add the code you are using to display the images ? Also the srcset are calculated by WP, you dont need to add new image sizes.
https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/responsive-images/#customizing-responsive-image-markup
